# Sqlalchemy groupby how do I know which value belongs to which group?

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, sqlalchemy

Say I have the following data:

```
Clicks           Device
-------------------------
  1              Mobile
  2              Desktop
  1              Tablet
  1              Mobile       
 ..                ..
```

I am querying the table as follows:

```
q = db_session.query(func.count(Website.Clicks)).group_by(Website.Device)


for a in q:
print(a)
```

The result is:

```
2
2
1
```

My question is how do I know which value belongs to which device? So for example how can I query a or output the following:

```
Mobile 2
Desktop 2
Tablet 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query only projects the count of Website Clicks, so that's all you're getting. Add the Devices to the projection:

```
q = db_session.query(Website.Device, func.count(Website.Clicks)).group_by(Website.Device)
```